# imagemagick convert PSD using -flatten and ignore hidden layers

Tags: imagemagick, jpeg, psd

I am currently using the following command to convert a PSD into a JPEG

```
convert.exe "input.psd" -flatten -resize 1280x-1  "output.jpg"
```

which outputs a JPEG that includes hidden layers.

Is there a way to flatten the PSD but ignore the hidden layers when creating the JPEG?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
convert.exe "input.psd[0]" -resize 1280x-1 "output.jpg"
```

This just uses layer "1" which should be your completed psd file.

I do not know what the -1 in your resize is supposed to do.

Comment: That worked great. The -1 keeps the output aspect ratio locked to the orginal.